# Efficiency of map::count followed by map::operator[]

Tags: c++, stl, std

There's a kind-of known problem that when a map contains some elements and the access to that element is needed, while the "element not found" situation is preferred to be handled by just if-check, there's still lacking a standard method to easily "please give me access to the element mapped at given key, tell me by some meaningful value that it doesn't exist, and let me access it otherwise".

My goal is: I need a clean, easy method, looking good an readably in the code, and, of course, efficient. This is the "official" way to do it:

```
map<int, vector<Command> > m;
map<int, vector<Command> >::iterator i = m.find(required_key);
if ( i == m.end() )
     error_not_found();
i->second.SetCode(x);
```

This is what I use, and prefer due to readability - my question is: **how less efficient is this method towards the official one above**:

```
map<int, vector<Command> > m;
if ( !m.count(required_key) )
   error_not_found();
m[required_key].SetCode(x);
```

Comment: Offtopic: `std::vector` does not have a `SetCode()` member.

Comment: it's *probably* twice as slow. It does the exact same job two times after all.

Comment: `else` are missing, else you don't have equivalent code (`operator []` would insert default value in *error* case).

Comment: @Jarod42 `error_not_found();` clearly denotes an early-out. Otherwise the first snippet would dereference `end()`.

Comment: two questions: 1) What do you mean with "official"? Can you give a reference? 2) Why do you think the second version is more readable? Maybe I am missing something, but to me they look almost the same (well, its one line less but now I have to understand that when using `count` actually a `find` is performed)

Comment: You can use [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) instead of `operator[]`. It throws if it isn't found.

Comment: @MaiLongdong: I'd like to handle the not-found-case in place. Using at() would generate an exception that I'd have to handle in place with a bloated handler code. This is not how exceptions were predicted to work - they were predicted to be handled gropuwise (multiple such errors come into a common handler).

Comment: @Quentin: that's exactly where my question goes. Can I count on that the compiler is smart enough to see that the work for searching for an element in the map done by `count()` is repeated on the same container, not modified in between, so it can reuse the result of searching in the next use of `operator[]`? Important thing is that this is a template-based class and both these methods are inline.

Comment: @Petr: yeah, this isn't any fragment of any real code, just wanted to have a long enough name of the instantiated map type. That was stupid anyway because I'm still writing it in C++11, so I can use `auto`.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer if `map::operator[]` return a proxy object, which adds an element to the map only when the assignment to the proxy object was done. This way, the default `operator[]` use in reading mode would do the same as `at()`, while the proxy object may have method, say, `get(fb)`, which would return the element at given key or the passed `fb` fallback value.

But I saw that the C++ Standard guys were considering it and dropped the idea because compilers would have problems with optimizing it. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious efficiency hit is that the lookup has to be done twice while in the "official" code, it is done once. For many accesses on a large map, this will be noticeable.  Notice too that even though the "official" code might be less readable, it is still well known and it also works on read-only maps.  C++11s `auto` might help with readability.

Answer (score 3):

Your method does the look-up twice, whereas the *official one* do it only once.
If `error_not_found();` throws, you may instead use `std::map::at` which throws when the key is not found and just have:

```
m.at(required_key).SetCode(x);
```

You may still write an helper function to *increase* readability and keeping performance:

```
template<typename Map, typename Key>
auto value(Map& m, const Key& key)
{
    auto it = m.find(key);

    return it == m.end() ? nullptr : std::addressof(it->second);
}
```

and then

```
std::map<int, Command> m;

auto* command = value(m, required_key);
if (command == nullptr) {
   return error_not_found();
}
command->SetCode(x);
```